# PDF Invoice Plus extension not showing in backend

Tags: magento-2.1, php, extensions

I purchased this extension today, but I am not able to install it.
I've got two folders app and lib. I have uploaded it to the root of my magento site

`run:`

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

and nothing. The extension is not showing. I am desperate **please help.**

Comment: first step whether u have used  php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Modulename

Comment: How to find that name? I've god folder pdfinvoiceplus_v1, and inside app and lib and so on. There is no mention of namespace modulename.

Comment: in the module registration.php you can find please check it.

Comment: have seen the Namespace_Modulename? in the registration.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below commands

```
php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Modulename
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
hp bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Thank you! Please note: Namespace_Modulename can be fount in module folder registration.php file.